# angular material doesn't show error message when add attribute dinamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My directive add some attributes dinamically. One these attributes is the "required".

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {})
    .directive("stPattern", ['$compile', stPattern]);

function stPattern($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element
                    .attr("ng-pattern", /^123$/)
                    .attr("required", "required");

                element.removeAttr("st-pattern"); //because compile loop

                $compile(element)($scope);
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
}
```

In my view I create a form with a input with error messages:

```
<form name="findForm">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>CA ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="findByCaId"
               ng-model="findByCaId"
               ng-focus="$event.target.select()"
               st-pattern="">

        <div ng-messages="findForm.findByCaId.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Campo obrigatório.</div>
            <div ng-message="pattern">Valor inválido para o campo CA ID.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

When I run the app, the verify happens well but the messages doesn't shows!
When I inspect the render code on browser with devtools I can see the message div was create well.

I noticed that when the message appears some CSS attributes are applied to the message:

```
style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"
```

Another thing i noticed is the asterisk on label which was should have on it.

That behavior is correct? Is a bug?

**###UPDATE###**

I added the $ timeout to keep the code similar to my problem scenario.

[I create a fiddle to example.](http://codepen.io/rafaeldev/pen/wJgaZV?editors=1010)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a plnkr or fiddle?

Comment: The asterisk is for required fields, to it appear, just add the attribute `required` on your `input`.

Comment: did you added the `ngMessages` to your angular module?

Comment: @LuizRossi, yes, I am importing

Comment: @lin, the o link to example: http://codepen.io/rafaeldev/pen/wJgaZV?editors=1010

Comment: @RafaelGomesFrancisco seems that the problem is that the CSS was already loaded, so is cannot change dynamically, I believe the validation  when the form be committed will be done, but probably you will need to change the object classes manually.

Comment: @LuizRossi, I found a workaround for my problem...
See that issue track on GH -> https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6767#issuecomment-234744952
It works for me. Thanks a lot for attention.

Comment: Good! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes in child nodes of `form` you have to recompile `form` directive, not that element.

So instead of `$compile(element)($scope);` use `$compile(element[0].form)($scope);`

Here is working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMMbGj?editors=1010

Comment: It's great Patryk! That's work for me! Thanks!
I just found it funny that now the field with the required attribute is displaying an error message twice...